# Dynamically created pages by users in MVC Pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-structures

I try to implement the dynamically created pages by users with MVC, C# . I mean the users can create a page that include components selected by users, while I am saying dynamic page. I don't mean dynamic datagrid on the page.

What should I do ?

How should I road to reach solution?

How should I design a structure?

Comment: How are the users going to create the pages, some sort of designer app?

Comment: Seems like good candidate to close - using any off the shelf CMS would be good approach... But - how/why WCF needs to be in he picture?

Comment: If this doesn't get closed then you need to give a lot more background to the problem you're trying to solve, along with what you have tried so far, such as some code snippets to give the question context.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It is not WCF, it's MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***According to the change of your title (MVC not WPF):***

You can keep/transfer data between requests in MVC by means of session state and a concept called Model-Binding which essentially helps you to hidrate an object from any object that you have in your controls, plus form variables, etc.

Here is more information regardless the use of session state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

and more info regarding MVC Model Binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

hope it helps

Comment: When the user wants to create a page, user must choose component of the page,like textbox etc. So I will need to keep page's components and their data. I have been trying design an approach to handle pages and their components, also data.

Comment: updated the post and your title to help others that might also help you with your enquiry.